# File Sync error. (auth failed (AUTH_FAILED))

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am getting 
"File Sync error. (auth failed (AUTH_FAILED))".

It brought in my other devices that are registered, registers this computer also....but it doesn't sync

this is what I did
http://pastebin.com/REkZrmDM

Comment: Relative to the procedure you have noted in your question, did you follow through on all of the steps?  What I found was that the first command listed returned an error associated with the fact that either ubuntuone-login or ubuntuone-preferences was not running.  Anyhow, I continued down the list and found that as soon as I issued the command `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone`, I found that UbuntuOne immediately began syncing.  I am just curious to know if you followed through procedure.

Comment: I did all the instructions as listed.

Comment: I am at a loss.  I will take a look around and see if I am able to dig up any additional information.

Comment: I don't know where you are getting problems, but I can say that I'm getting the same error just since I've upgraded to 11.04 because on Meerkat it worked fine. Also, I've followed the same guide you linked and when I try to kill the processes indicated, they seems like not running so no process is killed. It's very annoying not being able to use U1. Is there anyone who's able to use U1 on Natty?

Comment: Kory: you shouldn't use sudo to delete your own files. It's not necessary and you should never use sudo when it isn't necessary.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your clock and timezone correctly and then reconnecting. It worked for me.

I think this is because Ubuntu One synchronizes your files based on the time it was last modified.